# phpmyadmin пишет No database selected

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Помогите я сделал регистрацию на сайте всё отлично.Потом хочу сам зарегистрироваться на нём, но у меня пишет вот это "No database selected"?Я создал базу данных ввёл MySQL сервер,логин к этому серверу,"пароль к этому серверу и имя базы, к которой подключаюсь.Всё равно пишет ошибку.Вот код

```
 <?
    $db = mysql_connect ("localhost","logdoh","2345");
    mysql_select_db ("mysql",$db);
   ?>
```

Comment: А каким волшебством тут phpMyAdmin относится? Проверяйте параметры подключения и укажите правильное имя базы данных. В БД с именем mysql вам делать нечего, если вы конечно не какой-то велосипед а-ля phpMyAdmin пишете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_select_db ("mysql",$db);
```

БД так и называется mysql???

Вариантов не много, либо логин не тот, либо пароль, либо сервер ну и наконец название БД.

Comment: No database selected можно получить только в последнем случае) В остальных будет "Access denied for login@host ..."

Comment: Я в общем написал. ;) эт то да